# add windows defender service exception for internet radio

Tags: windows-8, windows-defender

I'm streaming internet radio from here: http://www.protonradio.com/player/live/player.php  and windows defender service is running pretty hard inspecting the stream as it comes in.  I trust the stream, is there anything I can do to turn this inspection off?

Comment: You can disable Windows Defender then enable it after your done.  What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: windows 8.  I leave it on for a large part of the day though.  Was hoping to bypass the stream url (I could probably pull it out of charles or firebug)

Comment: Windows Defender doesn't have a whitelist blacklist its either on or off.  You can try to exclude your browser's cache file but that would be a horrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use to add exceptions, you can revise for ProtonRadio..

```
;Add HOSTS to "Excluded Files and Locations" In Windows Defender
```

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths]
"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\HOSTS"=dword:00000000