# Does removing a drive letter prevent Windows Defender from scanning the drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, partitioning, windows-defender

I have one drive which is split into two partitions. One partition has Windows 10 installed and another has Windows 7. Does removing a drive letter trought Disk Management in Windows 10, of Windows 7 system and vice-versa, prevent Windows Defender from scanning the other systems files?

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a link to a similar question:
https://superuser.com/a/1039008 Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A partition without drive letter in this Windows installation cannot be accessed
by normal Windows applications and is in effect invisible.
It will also no longer be shown as a drive in File Explorer under "This PC"
and not be scanned by Defender.

Removing the drive letter is a well-known method for avoiding any Windows
access to a disk or partition.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: This is mostly true (the caveat is there), but volumes *can* be mounted as a folder and also be accessed using their volume id as in: https://superuser.com/questions/465730/ (only mention for completeness)